# update data on page load JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script allows you to calculate in real time the prices based on the number of selected product.

https://jsfiddle.net/sucwcokv/4/

But there is a problem .. if i se minimum 5 pieces for one product, the script does not re-calculate the price.

```
<input type="number" min="5" value="5" title="Qta" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
```

Example with problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/pzh57aaL/

there is a way to calculate it at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add

```
updateTotal();
```

at the end of your javascript and it will calculate on page load too.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6542whka/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the jQuery load is run when the page has been initialized.
You can call the method updateTotal in $(document).ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var subtotals = [];
 $('.input-text').change(function() {
    updateTotal();
  });
  updateTotal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function "updateTotal" inside "$(document).ready()" function.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
var subtotals = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

$('.input-text').change(function() {
    updateTotal();
});
```